# HDD Failure State Diagnostic and the Folowing Strategy

Tags: linux, hard-disk, dmesg

After 9+ years of work (accoring to SMART) my 2TB WD disk from NAS start failing to boot up. I've took that out and attached it to computer to see what's wrong.

Ubuntu Disks utility was fail to perform even a basic SMART test.

And there I've probably made a mistake issuing bare `fsck /dev/sdc4` command, since it ended up with an error message telling me it was unable to perform I/O ops.

System restart has made it even worse -- disk is now missing from `/dev/`.
So I've tried

> echo "0 0 0" >/sys/class/scsi_host/host2/scan

and consulted `dmesg`. It ran as follows:

```
[ 3592.252845] ata3: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[ 3592.253154] ata3.00: failed to IDENTIFY (INIT_DEV_PARAMS failed, err_mask=0x80)
[ 3602.797173] ata3: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
[ 3607.476986] ata3: COMRESET failed (errno=-16)
[ 3612.828731] ata3: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
[ 3613.008718] ata3: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[ 3614.919737] ata3.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:06:00:00:00:00 (SET FEATURES) succeeded
[ 3614.919743] ata3.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:00 (SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
[ 3614.919748] ata3.00: ACPI cmd b1/c1:00:00:00:00:00 (DEVICE CONFIGURATION OVERLAY) filtered out
[ 3614.964104] ata3.00: ATA-8: WDC WD20EARX-00PASB0, 51.0AB51, max UDMA/133
[ 3614.964107] ata3.00: 3907029168 sectors, multi 0: LBA48 NCQ (depth 32), AA
[ 3614.971180] ata3.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:06:00:00:00:00 (SET FEATURES) succeeded
[ 3614.971182] ata3.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:00 (SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
[ 3614.971183] ata3.00: ACPI cmd b1/c1:00:00:00:00:00 (DEVICE CONFIGURATION OVERLAY) filtered out
[ 3614.978286] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 3614.978378] scsi 2:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      WDC WD20EARX-00P AB51 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[ 3614.978564] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] 3907029168 512-byte logical blocks: (2.00 TB/1.82 TiB)
[ 3614.978566] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] 4096-byte physical blocks
[ 3614.978573] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[ 3614.978575] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[ 3614.978587] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[ 3614.979412] sd 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[ 3616.292596] ata3.00: exception Emask 0x50 SAct 0x400000 SErr 0x4090800 action 0xe frozen
[ 3616.292602] ata3.00: irq_stat 0x00400040, connection status changed
[ 3616.292606] ata3: SError: { HostInt PHYRdyChg 10B8B DevExch }
[ 3616.292610] ata3.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[ 3616.292618] ata3.00: cmd 60/08:b0:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/40 tag 22 ncq dma 4096 in
                       res 40/00:b4:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x50 (ATA bus error)
[ 3616.292621] ata3.00: status: { DRDY }
[ 3616.292626] ata3: hard resetting link
[ 3622.052321] ata3: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
[ 3626.312084] ata3: COMRESET failed (errno=-16)
[ 3626.312094] ata3: hard resetting link
[ 3627.024061] ata3: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[ 3632.259814] ata3.00: qc timeout (cmd 0xec)
[ 3632.259825] ata3.00: failed to IDENTIFY (I/O error, err_mask=0x5)
[ 3632.259828] ata3.00: revalidation failed (errno=-5)
[ 3632.259838] ata3: hard resetting link
[ 3634.911683] ata3: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[ 3634.911690] ata3.00: link offline, clearing class 1 to NONE
[ 3634.913110] ata3: hard resetting link
[ 3635.703642] ata3: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[ 3635.704007] ata3.00: failed to IDENTIFY (INIT_DEV_PARAMS failed, err_mask=0x80)
[ 3635.704011] ata3.00: revalidation failed (errno=-5)
[ 3635.704017] ata3.00: disabled
[ 3640.707392] ata3: hard resetting link
[ 3641.025705] ata3: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[ 3641.026010] ata3.00: failed to IDENTIFY (INIT_DEV_PARAMS failed, err_mask=0x80)
[ 3646.083079] ata3: hard resetting link
[ 3646.397432] ata3: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[ 3646.397723] ata3.00: failed to IDENTIFY (INIT_DEV_PARAMS failed, err_mask=0x80)
[ 3646.397728] ata3: limiting SATA link speed to 3.0 Gbps
[ 3651.458883] ata3: hard resetting link
[ 3651.774094] ata3: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 320)
[ 3651.774429] ata3.00: failed to IDENTIFY (INIT_DEV_PARAMS failed, err_mask=0x80)
[ 3656.834574] ata3: hard resetting link
[ 3657.149507] ata3: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 320)
[ 3657.149530] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#22 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 3657.149534] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#22 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current]
[ 3657.149538] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#22 Add. Sense: Unaligned write command
[ 3657.149542] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#22 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[ 3657.149544] print_req_error: 2 callbacks suppressed
[ 3657.149547] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[ 3657.149553] buffer_io_error: 2 callbacks suppressed
[ 3657.149555] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc, logical block 0, async page read
[ 3657.149573] ata3: EH complete
[ 3657.149582] ata3.00: detaching (SCSI 2:0:0:0)
[ 3657.149629] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[ 3657.149635] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc, logical block 0, async page read
[ 3657.149691] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[ 3657.149696] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc, logical block 0, async page read
[ 3657.149711] ldm_validate_partition_table(): Disk read failed.
[ 3657.149737] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[ 3657.149741] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc, logical block 0, async page read
[ 3657.149777] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[ 3657.149780] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc, logical block 0, async page read
[ 3657.149812] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[ 3657.149816] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc, logical block 0, async page read
[ 3657.149847] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[ 3657.149851] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc, logical block 0, async page read
[ 3657.149865] Dev sdc: unable to read RDB block 0
[ 3657.149886] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[ 3657.149889] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc, logical block 0, async page read
[ 3657.149920] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[ 3657.149924] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc, logical block 0, async page read
[ 3657.149964] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 24 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[ 3657.149968] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc, logical block 3, async page read
[ 3657.150033]  sdc: unable to read partition table
[ 3657.166693] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Read Capacity(16) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 3657.166695] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Sense not available.
[ 3657.166718] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 3657.166719] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Sense not available.
[ 3657.166736] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] 0 512-byte logical blocks: (0 B/0 B)
[ 3657.166737] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] 4096-byte physical blocks
[ 3657.166769] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
[ 3657.167107] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Stopping disk
[ 3657.167124] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Start/Stop Unit failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
```

From that I understood that the HDD has bad sectors making that failing to even attach properly, not saying about a recognition of any of those 3 existing partitions (EXT3 or 4, I forgot).

So I now want to decide on a further strategy.

First I'd like to see that HDD under `/dev/` again, but don't known if it even possible. Next I'd to deal with those bad blocks. Or should I first of all to copy data with `dd` (or some other tool) into a safe place?

Comment: `smartctl -a /dev/sdc` and urgently consider using `ddrescue` to recover the disk before any more of it dies

Comment: @roaima There's `[sdd] Stopping disk` as per dmesg, so this smartctl command ends with `No such device`.

Comment: Is it `sdc` or `sdd` now? Make sure you're referencing the right one

Comment: @roaima `sdc` (or `sdd` as I've tried to connected it to another ata later) is not under `/dev`.

Comment: Is this device USB connected? Maybe it's not getting enough power to operate properly

Comment: @roaima No, it's connected with 15pin SATA power supply.